# Avoid overlapping while resizing a panel in flex

Tags: apache-flex, resize, panel, overlapping, hittest

In my application i am using a borderContainer which contains two or more panels.All these panels are resizable.
My problem is while resizing a panel if it touches the panel next to it i have to stop resizing automatically.
I used hittestObject and able to catch the hitting point but i dont know how to stop resize event.
Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this code but you can try. :). Basically I have to use the **preventDefault** method whenever I need to stop the execution of the default behavior of that specific method.

```
<mx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.containers.Panel;
        import mx.events.ResizeEvent;

    //Your other codes here

    public function panel_resizeHandler(event:ResizeEvent):void
    {
          var isTouched:Boolean = firstPanel.hitTestObject(secondPanel);

            if(isTouched)
            {
                event.preventDefault();   
            }

    }
    ]]>
</mx:Script>

<mx:Panel id="firstPanel" resize="panel_resizeHandler(event)>
    <!-- Panel contents here-->
</mx:Panel>
<mx:Panel id="secondPanel" ">
    <!--Panel Contents Here -->
</mx:Panel>
```